# Can Visual studio plugins get notified of c++ build/CL tasks/calls to CL.EXE?

Tags: visual-studio, thread-priority

I would like my cl.exe (the c++ compiler process) processes to run at lower than normal priority so that my UI threads are not affected.  I have turned on /MP builds for most of my projects and want to take advantage of all the CPUs, but don't want the box to be bogged down and unusable.

A co-worker wrote a utility that monitors threads and allows users to select process names to drop priorities for, but I was wondering if it might be possible to write a plugin for visual studio that was notified on all calls to CL.exe so that you can programmatically lower the priority.

So, is this possible? 
VS 2008 - C++  builds for now.

Answer (score 1):

You have the [BuildEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa301273(VS.71).aspx) object that the DTE exposes, it will be for triggered all types of project but its a good stating point to see if the CL is running. (There are some examples on how to use it in [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&sa=N&q=BuildEvents++lang:c%23&ct=rr&cs_r=lang:c%23)).
Or (And this is hacky and I don't know if it will work) you can write a CL.exe replacer that will run the actual CL at low/ideal priority and route all the parameters to it.

Answer (score 0):

While this does not answer your question, I have done the same as your colleague - wrote a small utility that lowers priority of `cl.exe`, you can grab the [source code / binary](http://www.stud.fit.vutbr.cz/~xpolok00/coolstuff.htm#link28) here.